# Set CEdit text in MFC Window designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I do MFC form design in form designer. Is it possible to set somehow default CEdit text from designer without code writing? If not what is the best place to set CEdit text at application start?

Comment: Give some more details.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set text from the designer.

If in a view, your best bet is to initialize in `OnInitialUpdate()`.

If in a dialog, you want `OnInitDialog()`.